# is it possible to connect pc from one room to other room T.V using KVM over ip?

Tags: usb, ethernet, hdmi, switch, kvm-switch

i want to connect my pc to the a T.V in other room but also control it from the other room[gaming/internet browsing/movies], from what i found that can be accomplished by using a KVM over ip, since it my first time messing with these thing i want to be sure that what i order will work for me best[this? https://www.amazon.com/Extender-Support-Keyboard-Ethernet-Lossless-Near/dp/B081W94ZNF/ref=redir_mobile_desktop?ie=UTF8&ref_=psdcmw_13983771_t2_B01EV33R8S]

[sadly to run HD/USB cables directly from pc to T.V is not an option for me :/ ]

i also draw a diagram so it can be more visual, any help and feedback will be very appreciated :)

[image]

Comment: Let me get this straight, you want to remotely connect your computer to your TV, and you want to be able to control it with peripherals at the TV, right?

Comment: yes, so i can plug controller or keyboard to the kvm switch in the other side(T.V) and control the P.C from the T.V

Comment: What is your goal exactly? Do you want to watch movies through this? Play games? Or just general computer use?

Comment: do both :) but mostly gaming

Comment: I see, well then, the answer to your question is yes. It's an expensive solution, but it should get the job done just right.

There exist other cheaper options but most of them come with caveats such as increased latency (for example steam link, although those aren't being sold anymore sadly). The potentially cheapest solution would be to ues a long HDMI cable, you could then use another computer (spare laptop, or raspberry pi for example) and connect a keyboard and mouse through it to your PC via a software solution like Synergy.

Comment: Some "smart" TV's allow remote access to a PC, e.g. Samsun'g: https://www.samsung.com/ca/support/tv-audio-video/how-to-use-the-remote-access-on-your-samsung-smart-tv/ . That said, I doubt a fast game would be playable.